# Finding Rotation and Translation between three coordinate systems

Tags: camera, rotation, geometry, translation, calibration

If we have three coordinate systems namely A, B, and C and we know the [R|t] from A to B and A to C. Then how can we find the [R|t] between B and C?

Answer (score 1):

From B to C is from B to A to C, so you need to invert the first transformation and combine it with the second.

I assume that by [R|t] you mean the rotation matrix plus translation vector. It might be easier to consider these two as a [single square matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#Augmented_matrix) operating on homogeneous coordinates. For planar operations that would be a 3×3 matrix, for 3d operations it would be 4×4. That way you can use regular matrix inversion and multiplication to describe your combined result.

Comment: Is [R|t] a 3×3 matrix or a 3×4 matrix? Normally [R] is a 3×3 matrix and [t] is a 3×1 vector right?

Comment: @Udaya: Sorry, I'm used to operating in the plane, so for me an inhomogeneous setup would have a 2×2 rotation and a 2×1 translation. If you are in 3d then you want a 4×4 matrix for the whole thing.